# Postback from Dynamic Content

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, webusercontrol

I am dynamically building some HTML content on a WebForms page, using `HtmlGenericControl()`.

```
HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
// ...
ListItems.Controls.Add(p);
```

But now I need to add a button to the paragraph created above, and the button needs to do a postback when clicked.

Must I completely rework this code to load child controls, which can contain real server-side buttons? Or is there a way to inject buttons capable of some type of postback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a test method and test EventHandler that, if called, will add a button control with a server-side Click event to ListItems.  The commented-out code will change the markup of the ListItems object if InnerHtml is available but I rethought that approach and assumed the existence of a textbox on the page that would show the results of the click event firing.  There are a number of concerns that you'll want to handle if you need those child controls to be present from one postback to another, though- for instance, if Test() isn't called every time the page loads that button won't be created and there will be no way to call its EventHandler unless other controls also call it.

```
      public void Test()
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl p = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("p");
        p.InnerHtml = @"<strong>Test</strong>";
        // ...
        ListItems.Controls.Add(p);
        Button b = new Button();
        b.ID = "cmdTest";
        b.Text = "Test";
        b.Click += new EventHandler(test_Click);
        p.Controls.Add(b);
    }

    protected void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // ListItems.InnerHtml = "Test button clicked";
        txtTestResults.Text = "Test button clicked at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the aspx page? I'm thinking of `<div id="someid" runat="server" serversideclick="eventname"></div>` or something along those lines.